# Read Dropbox txt File

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

Well i am trying to make a Register and have this code

```
 Dim webs As New Net.WebClient
 Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvobcpniczdx1s0/regList.txt)

Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click
    If TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text + TextBox4.Text = reader.ReadToEnd Then
        MsgBox("You have Registered Succesfully")
    Else
        MsgBox("You Failed To register")
    End If
End Sub
```

What im trying to do is make it read the dropbox .txt file and say, if the 4 text boxes all add up to the dropbox txtfile then it will register succesfully

in the dropbox the registration key is "aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd"
and when i put it in 5 digits in the 4 boxes it says failed (n)

the only way it works if i do all the 4 boxes add up to =  "aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant read the Dropbox txt like this. I found out, that if ther is a not fitting parameter, dropbox gives out the raw file. just use the url and add anything like this:

`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wvobcpniczdx1s0/regList.txt?insert_anything_you_want`

But watch out of the **?**!

Answer (score 1):

to get the plan text from a file located at dropbox server, we have the below link

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wvobcpniczdx1s0/regList.txt?dl=0
```

Now we need to read the text from the link..

```
Dim address As String = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/82wlkg6l4idkewk/KPRAVEENSTOCKS.txt?dl=0"
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
        MsgBox(reader.ReadToEnd)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
    Private Sub cmdRegister_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegister.Click

Dim address As String = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/82wlkg6l4idkewk/KPRAVEENSTOCKS.txt?dl=0"
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
            Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))


        If TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text + TextBox4.Text = reader.ReadToEnd Then
            MsgBox("You have Registered Succesfully")
        Else
            MsgBox("You Failed To register")
        End If
    End Sub
```